# Multiple JavaScript Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I include the following in my header

```
<!-- scripts -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.infinitecarousel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/news.ticker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.autogrowtextarea.js"></script>
```

but the autogrowtextarea dont work if the script.js,jquery.infinitecarousel.js and  news.ticker.js are included, but if i remove those three lines my autogrow textbox function work, why can this be. thanks

Comment: Is there any error output? Have you checked to see if there are any identically named functions in those files?

Comment: what error do you get? Have you removed one by one the offending js files to see which one actually is causing problems?

Comment: i dont get any erros, the textarea yust does not expand automaticaly

Answer (score 4):

That means that something in one or all of those scripts is masking or breaking the functionality, or something on which it depends.  Try not including the scripts one by one; isolate which one causes the break.  Then look for duplicate definitions.  Also, make sure that the scripts are included in the right order if there are any dependencies.

Comment: @ex0b1t The fancy programmer term for this is "debugging".

Comment: i have to have all 3 the scrips disabled for the autogrowtextarea to work. and i dont see any duplicate functions

Answer (score 0):

Try to put `<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.autogrowtextarea.js"></script>` next to the include of jquery and before the other ones and test if works. Maybe you have dependencies in the other files (script.js)

Comment: script is dependent on infinitecarousel and the other only depend on jquery, i have tried them in all the orders, and i have looked for functions with the same name, but to no avail. any other ideas